# return percentage of records based on value in column

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm working on a sql query that needs to get a percentage of the records based on the value of a particular column.  The percentage is given by the user.  A stripped down version of the query is below

```
SELECT OrganizationID,
       CustomerID,
       OrderID
  FROM x
```

The output would look something like

```
 OrganizationID, CustomerID, OrderID 
  123             abc         p456
  123             cba         p457 
  123             bac         p458 
  456             def         p987 
  456             efd         p988
```

I need to be able to pull say 50 percent of the output for each organizationid. So in this example I'd come back with 2-3 records.  Which records doesnt matter as long as the correct percentage of the records is pulled.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT OrganizationID,
                CustomerID,
                OrderID,
                COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY OrganizationID) AS C,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrganizationID 
                                       ORDER BY (SELECT 0))     AS RN
         FROM   YourTable)
SELECT OrganizationID,
       CustomerID,
       OrderID
FROM   CTE
WHERE  RN <= CEILING(0.5 * C)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/290e3/2)

Comment: I deleted my answer after discovering that it didn't work with (real) tables. I tested locally using table variables, it worked fine with them, but not with tables.

Comment: @AndriyM I still think it's a bug though and that query should work. Wonder if it is taking the count from the whole table not just the rows matching the `WHERE`. Will try and work it out later!

Comment: When you do, you'll find that the plans are almost completely identical. They only differ slightly in the non-zero percentages (both table scans' costs are 17% each for table vars versus 16% for tables, and the index spool's cost is 67% vs 68%).

Comment: @AndriyM - From here [The top then requests the row count from the spool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2007/08/01/more-on-top.aspx) but the difference is the type of spool. When it works it uses a table spool that is populated separately for each different outer row. When it doesn't work it uses an index spool that is populated once with all the rows then seeked into. It seems to still use the row count from the entire spool however in calculating the percentage.

Comment: In my opinion this is a bug and it ought to use the filtered row count in the index spool case not the total row count. I've posted it here https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/778200/incorrect-inconsistent-results-for-cross-apply-select-top-x-percent

Comment: @SQLKiwi: Thanks, this does seem worth posting as a question. I doubt I will post it myself, though. Primarily because I'll be unable to provide the necessary details or fail to do that properly due to my inexperience. Mind you, I was even unable to spot that the plans I mentioned previously used different kind of spool (Table vs Index)! Of course, asking a good question doesn't necessarily *require* good knowledge, but in my particular case it would also be poor quality. I'll be happy if Martin takes the trouble, although he seems to have already make his mind up about this being a bug.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, Martin. And sorry about cluttering your comment thread.

Comment: @AndriyM - I'm happy to ask it as a question if you don't want to and SQLKiwi disagrees that it is a bug or has more to say on the issue. I don't think you should be put off asking it yourself though. The question just needs to ask something like why the table variable version yields different results.

Comment: @SQLKiwi - Agree might be better/easier to disallow it rather than fix it as window functions can be used instead. `CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (50) PERCENT * FROM (SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE OrganizationID = org.OrganizationID) T) x;` still gives the same results as the original query which seems clearly wrong.